# Flashing folder when booting up mac

Tags: mac, disk-utility

When I'm booting up my macbook pro from 2011, and one day it randomly started showing a flashing folder. I didn't do anything special with it before that, and when I go to disk utility, it shows no hard drive at all. When it boots up all I see is disk0 and and under that Mac OS X Base System. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The flashing folder means it can't find a valid OS install to boot from. There are three ways to recover from that:

1. **Local recovery mode.** Your Mac's boot drive normally has a small hidden partition with a stripped-down macOS install on it that's just enough to boot your machine and let you use Disk Utility to try to fix your disk, and then, if needed, start an OS re-install. If your disk is not too badly corrupted, this might work. To enter local recovery mode, hold down <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (Command-R) at boot.
2. **Internet recovery mode.** Your 2011 MacBook Pro's original firmware didn't support Internet Recovery mode, but if you installed the right firmware update a year or two later, it does now. Internet Recovery does a "net boot": it creates a RAM disk (I believe; I don't *think* it needs a working disk, but I could be wrong) and then connects to an Apple recovery server on the Internet to download a minimal macOS recovery image to boot from. Try this if local recovery didn't work. To enter Internet recovery mode, hold down <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (Command-Option-R) at boot. Your computer will need an Internet connection via a simple Wi-Fi network, or via Ethernet.
3. **Boot from an external drive.** If you don't already have macOS installed on an external drive of some sort, **use another Mac** to set one up. Or boot another Mac into Target Disk Mode and connect it via Thunderbolt to your dead Mac to use the good Mac's internal drive as a boot drive for your dead Mac. There are also ways to use a macOS installer app to create a bootable macOS installer image on an external drive such as a USB flash drive. Note that I said "use another **Mac**" to create your bootable macOS install on an external drive. Anyone who tries to find a way to create bootable macOS drives from Windows or Linux usually fails. Apple has never made this easy to do from other OSes. Save yourself the pain and just use another Mac for this.